# TypeError: Path must be a string. DOCKER REACT

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm

I can run my react app locally (either on windows and linux) by typing  in console

```
npm run
```

but when i try run it in docker container it runs and listening on port 3001, but when i open the app by browser i have following error (with internal server error response):

```
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1236:7)
    at noopServiceWorkerMiddleware (/app/node_modules/react-dev-utils/noopServiceWorkerMiddleware.js:14:26)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at launchEditorMiddleware (/app/node_modules/react-dev-utils/errorOverlayMiddleware.js:20:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at handleWebpackInternalMiddleware (/app/node_modules/react-dev-utils/evalSourceMapMiddleware.js:42:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

my docker file:

```
# base image
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json

RUN npm uninstall -g jest
RUN npm install -g jest
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install

RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.0 -g --silent

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "randevou-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.4",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.12.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

i run container by typing

```
docker run -d -v /app -v /app/node_modules -p 3001:3000 --rm randevoureact
```

on container, my node version is 8.10.0 and my npm version is 5.6.0
i'm totally newbie at dockers and front-end issues

i don't know if it is importat but im using react-router in my react application
can somebody help me :(?

Comment: Did you try `-v ${PWD}:/app` instead of `-v /app`?

Comment: that is correct answer ! GIVE HIM A TACO!
thx Stefan, i was really angry and writing in stackoverflow was my last resort :)

Comment: Better still would be to delete both `-v` options and use the code that you're actually building into the image.  You can use a local Node environment for live development and it will interact fine with Docker-based backends.